# Jquery UI Accordion - Cancel Change

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have been wrestling with this one for a while now.

I want to have a confirm() before someone changes the accordion.

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var edited = false;

    $(".accordion-me").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        changestart: function(event, ui) {
            if (edited) {
                if (!confirm("You have unsaved changes. Do you want to navigate away?") {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

With little joy! I have also tried something like this

```
   $(".accordion-me h3").each(function() {

                    $(this).unbind("click");

                    $(this).click(function(e) {

                        if (confirm("You have unsaved changes! Do you want to navigate away?")) {
                            $(this).unbind("click");
                            $(".accordion-me").accordion({
                                autoHeight: false,
                                navigation: true,
                                changestart: function(event, ui) {
                                    if (edited) {
                                        if (!confirm("You have unsaved changes. Do you want to navigate away?") {
                                            event.preventDefault();
                                            event.stopPropagation();
                                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });                            
                            $(this).click();
                        }
                    });
                });
```

But again with no joy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Use an empty event when creating the accordion, which will allow you to manage the click event of the accordion using a jQuery .click function.
You can then process the confirm box and allow the accordion click event to be executed only if confirmed.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var edited = false,
        accordion_me = $('.accordion-me');

    // activate the accordion, but with an empty event
    accordion_me.accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        event: ''
    });

    // here's the new accordion event
    $('.accordion-me h3').click(function()
    {
        // find the index of the event being called
        var i = $('.accordion-me h3').index(this);

        // if we have unsaved changes and do not confirm, stop accordion execution      
        if (edited && !confirm('You have unsaved changes. Do you want to navigate away?'))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // continue with the accordion execution. Activate the requested event index.
        accordion_me.accordion('activate', i);

        return false;
    });
});
```

If your accordion is collapsible (as mine is) your accordion will still work as it did before.
Also, if you only have 1 accordion, I would recommend using an id to call it instead of the .accordion-me class, which will save some overhead.
If you still need to use a class to call it, put an html tag before it, i.e. div.accordion-me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind it to the click event on the anchor tag. For example, if your header links are:

```
<a href="#" class="accordionHeaderLink">header 1</a>
```

code would be (also in the document.ready function)

```
$('.accordionHeaderLink').click(function(){
    if (!confirm("You have unsaved changes. Do you want to navigate away?")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue using the ui dialog confirmation. I still cannot get that to work, even binding it to the click event. The accordion changes as the ui dialog is coming up.